# Using certain values from a matrix in MATLAB and setting other values to zero?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to only plot values that correspond to a certain angle and zero the other columns.

Basically, I have a row matrix with elevation angles and I only want to plot the values above 5 deg and just zero the rest. It should be simple, but I don't know why I can't get it to work.

With this, I am getting a matrix with all zeros...

```
vis(1,:)=ge(sat_elev(1,:),5*deg2rad);
if  vis(1,:)==1
    vis(1,:)=sat_elev(1,:);
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to plot only values above a certain value but *maintaining the original x-axis positions*: set unwanted values to `NaN`. That way plotting commands will ignore them.

Example:

```
angles = [10 8 3 6 14 25 4 1 20 3 17];
threshold = 5;
angles(angles<=threshold) = NaN;
stem(angles) %// or plot(angles, 'o')
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that is a better way than setting to zero. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example with this dummy vector:

```
DummyAngles =

     1     4     7    15    16     4     2     9     2     4     5     5    10
```

1) set the elements < 5 to 0

```
DummyAngles(DummyAngles < 5) = 0

DummyAngles =

     0     0     7    15    16     0     0     9     0     0     5     5    10
```

2) Remove those elements without setting them to 0 at all:

```
DummyAngles(DummyAngles < 5) = []

DummyAngles =

     7    15    16     9     5     5    10
```

You can then get the corresponding y-values so that the lengths match. In your case the 1st solution will ensure that lengths are equal.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. My problem actually was that I wasn't converting back to radians, so it was all zeros. Woops. All fixed now :)

Comment: what about if I have a 3x3 and I want to make the other corresponding values NaN when less than 5 deg? Tried this but I don't think I am using ISNAN correctly.                                 sat_elev(sat_elev < 5*deg2rad) = NaN;
sat_look_tcs=[sat_elev;sat_azim;range]; 

if ISNAN(sat_look_tcs(1,:))
     sat_look_tcs(2:3,:)=NaN;
end